# docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to install Hortonworks Sandbox in mac using docker
but I got this error

'''
docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
'''

Comment: can you share your docker run command ?

Comment: `repository name must be lowercase`, then why you choose to ignore this indication?

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this problem, and solved it.

Check that no folder in your current working directory where you run `docker run` contains uppercase letters. Change to lowercase if that's the case and try again. That seemed to work for me.